# Рекурсивно перебирать папки и файлы на nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

почему этот код не работает, scaner() ищет подпапку в корневом папке,что здесь не так?

```
const fs = require('fs');


function scaner(y){
    let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
    for(let x of y1){
        let stat = fs.statSync(x);
        if(!stat.isFile()){
            let path = y + x + '/';
            scaner(path);
        }
    }
}
scaner('./');
```

Comment: Подумайте что вы передаёте в `fs.statSync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');


function scaner(y){
    let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
    for(let x of y1){
        let stat = fs.statSync(y + x); // тут забыли путь
        if(!stat.isFile()){
            let path = y + x + '/';
            scaner(path);
        }
    }
}
scaner('./');
```